# LED moving head bearing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, bearings, lighting

I'm in the process of building a simple led moving head like [This ADJ Pocket Pro](https://www.bax-shop.nl/led-moving-head/american-dj-pocket-pro-led-moving-head), my POC will be much simpler but you get the direction I'm going. Electronics are working, now I just need a proper way of assembling it, but I'm stuck at finding a way to rotate and attach it all together.

The device will have 2 rotation points. One attached to the base moving left and right, and the second one being the head going up and down. The cables must run through the bearing, every unit I saw so far has it like that. The base bearing and one head bearing will have a gear connected which in turn will have a belt leading to a gear on a stepper motor. Much like a 3D printer.

I've looked at some [basic bearings](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004115049685.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.77391803m7Z2kQ&algo_pvid=76899c68-c3b0-4460-9b9c-c86cc0704d9f&aem_p4p_detail=2023091211313119327838626386720000861874&algo_exp_id=76899c68-c3b0-4460-9b9c-c86cc0704d9f-0&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%2112.25%216.61%21%21%2112.85%21%21%40211b88ee16945434919021162e0558%2112000028083120267%21sea%21NL%21758712932%21S&curPageLogUid=wL2XFWgAhm3Q&search_p4p_id=2023091211313119327838626386720000861874_1) on aliexpress which can be press fitted, these could work for mounting the head as the head will be inbetween 2 bearings making it impossible to fall out. I could use 1 bearing attached to a gear with a rod on one side which will take care of the movement. The other bearing could be used for leading cables through. The bearings could be press fitted into the "arms" holding the head. But I'm not sure how to connect the head to the inner part of the bearing with the cables as most bearings do not have any way of connecting it except a rod. That won't work because of the cables. I cannot use a slip ring because there are too many wires, and possibly too many amps going through it as well.

Then I also got the rotating part at the base. Here cables need to go through as well so a rod is out of the question.

Now I've been browsing around a bit and found [these RU type bearings](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005608183336.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.45.66b426cfSITAmq&algo_pvid=3258d08b-ad2a-4677-a2ed-35eed8d21d0c&aem_p4p_detail=202309121123208387854672128560000805288&algo_exp_id=3258d08b-ad2a-4677-a2ed-35eed8d21d0c-22&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%2137.07%2137.07%21%21%21283.87%21%21%40211b88ef16945430005731617eb7ce%2112000033736249067%21sea%21NL%21758712932%21S&curPageLogUid=fsfFf87g07Jc&search_p4p_id=202309121123208387854672128560000805288_23) on Aliexpress. They look like they would do the job because I can just screw both sides in. Also great because a moving head can hang upside down and I trust a screw more to hold the thing together than a press fit. Problem is they get expensive real fast. Especially when you buy them elsewhere those things cost more than the moving head listed above... Now considering there are cheap moving heads around 100 euro's, there must be another way to get this done.

I've also looked at some [teardown video's](https://youtu.be/i3dHP6ehGY0?si=jwueFjJKahsGnO5v&t=1593) to gain some more knowledge. Unfortunatly none focus on the bearings used. This one looks a lot like the RU type mentioned above. But this is a cheap chinese light so I doubt it has expensive bearings in it.

Any suggestions on this are welcome. Maybe I'm just looking at the wrong component. If really needed I can 3D print some custom bearings as the project would be small enough that weight would not be that big of a deal. But I prefer a proper solution as I do not know how long a printed bearing would last, especially since the lamp can get warm.

Comment: why do you have to pass the cables through the base? ... the projector could be mounted on a post and the cables could be loosely wrapped around the post as the projector head rotates

Comment: A device for passing current from stationary to rotating? Contact based solutions include the brushes on a brushed motor, and devices called slip rings.  There are also some pretty neat electromagnetic and optical non-contact solutions...

Comment: @jsotola Yes I could but considering even cheap moving heads of 100 euro have cables through the bearing I figured it should be achievable and not too expensive. It should create less wear as the cables don't have to wrap around the post the whole time as the unit can move 360+ degrees, but are free to move within the opening of the bearing. I did eventually find a bearing called a KFL007 which could do the trick if I use a hollow pipe. But it would not be as strong as the RU bearings I mentioned before and I see similar bearings as the RU type being used in the cheap moving heads

Comment: @Abel Yes I had a look at slip rings, but considering a moving head can easily use 10-20 cables in it's most basic form that would be impossible. Same goes for the electromagnetic and optical solutions. Both cheap and expensive moving heads all use cables through their bearings. So I would expect there is a simpler and more cost effective solution to this problem.

Comment: Simplest solution: build enough slack and (active) cable management into your design for the full range of motion.  You obviously don't need infinite range of motion as 10-20 cables through a bearing wouldn't achieve that.  Through bearing (hollow shaft) just happens to be one of the cheapest way to achieve such by minimizing the difference over range of motion to simplify the cable management.  Get yourself some hollow shafts and hollow shaft steppers and be done? Bearings just need to be sized for load.